# Content Negotiation with URI Extensions on Custom URLs

Tags: grails

I was changing some URLs in UrlMappings from the default to something new. The default return format is JSON, and an XML response can still be retrieved by `xxx?format=xml`. However, the method by URI extensions stopped working (xxx.json or xxx.xml) which is something I still would like to have. Is there any way to add this back into place?

Original (URI extension working):

```
"/api/companies"(resources:"company")  {
    "/infos"(resources:"companyInfo")
}
```

To (URI extension not working):

```
"/api/companies"(resources:"company")  {
    "/info"(controller:"companyInfo", action: 'show', method: 'GET')
    "/info"(controller:"companyInfo", action: 'save', method: 'POST')
    "/info"(controller:"companyInfo", action: 'update', method: 'PUT')
    "/info"(controller:"companyInfo", action: 'delete', method: 'DELETE')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the format capture (using `(.$format)?`) to the URI:

```
"/api/companies"(resources:"company")  {
    "/info(.$format)?"(controller:"companyInfo", action: 'show', method: 'GET')
    "/info(.$format)?"(controller:"companyInfo", action: 'save', method: 'POST')
    "/info(.$format)?"(controller:"companyInfo", action: 'update', method: 'PUT')
    "/info(.$format)?"(controller:"companyInfo", action: 'delete', method: 'DELETE')
}
```

Comment: Hmm, in my case this doesn't work. I guess, I must have some issue elsewhere. Using 2.3.7. Thanks.